# Cannot start HBase start_hbase.sh: command not found

Tags: solr, cygwin, hbase, nutch

Trying, in vain so far, to make Nutch + Solr work. I'm having very hard time understanding how to go about this thing with `nutch` and `solr`. I have followed all the tutorials I could find on the internet, most of them for older versions, but I still could not make any of them work. At this moment I'm follwoing this [guide](https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup)

I have unpacked **nutch 2.2.1**, **sorl 4.3.1**, **hbase 0.90.4** to directory on my xampp local server (none of the tutorials said where I should unpack them to, so I assumed that on local server).

I'm using `Cygwin` on windows 7. JAVA_HOME is pointing to `/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/java/jdk1.8.0_05`

I stuck at `Configure HBase` step. As the tutorial dictates I have configured `/hbase-0.90.4/conf/hbase-site.xml` as follows:

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/trynutch/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
   <value>C:/xampp/htdocs/trynutch/zookeeper</value>
</property>
```

As per tutorial after this I should be able to run the following command:

```
$ ./trynutch/hbase/bin/start_hbase.sh
```

When I run it in cygwin terminal, it gives an error:

```
DM@comp ~
$ cd C:/xampp/htdocs/trynutch/hbase-0.90.4/bin

DM@comp /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/trynutch/hbase-0.90.4/bin
$ start_hbase.sh
-bash: start_hbase.sh: command not found
```

I'd appreciate any information.

Comment: try with following commmand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with following command:

```
./start_hbase.sh
```

if its not runnable then try after making it runnable, to make runnable use following command:

```
chmod a+x start_hbase.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

you just try `sh start-hbase.sh` from the hbase bin directory.

```
cd C:/xampp/htdocs/trynutch/hbase-0.90.4/bin
sh start-hbase.sh
```